# Procesamiento paralelo de matrices por columnas con MPI

Tags: c

Tengo una matriz (c) de 10x10 (M=10) elementos en la cual divido la matriz por filas para que sean ejecutadas por 5 procesos (esclavos=5) diferentes con lo que a cada proceso le corresponde 2 filas de esa matriz.

```
offset = 0;
filas = (M / esclavos);
MPI_Send(&c[offset][0], filas*M, MPI_DOUBLE, id_esclavo,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
offset= offset+filas;
```

Ahora quiero dividir la matriz pero por columnas. Probe de la siguiente manera cambiando los indices de la matriz pero no funciona:

```
MPI_Send(&c[0][offset], filas*M, MPI_DOUBLE, id_esclavo,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

¿Saben como hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente. No nos muestras que hacen esas funciones **MPI_Send** ni nos muestras todos el codigo, es mas dificil ayudarte de esa manera.

Comment: [MPI_Send](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Send.html) es una función de biblioteca con lo que no es en absoluto necesario mostrar qué hace la función. La pregunta está correctamente formulada y un experto en [MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/) sería capaz de responderla.

Answer (score 1):

El problema tiene que ver con la forma en que se organiza la memoria en un array en C.

`&c[offset][0]` es un puntero al primer elemento de la fila `offset`. Entonces `(&c[offset][0])+1` va a ser un puntero al segundo elemento de la fila `offset`.

Pero `&c[0][offset]` es un puntero al primer elemento de la columna `offset` y `(&c[0][offset])+1` no es un puntero al segundo elemento de la columna `offset` , sino que es un puntero al primer elemento de la columna `offset+1`.

Es decir, la memoria en el array está organizada de forma que los elementos de una misma fila están en posiciones consecutivas en memoria. La memoria está organizada por filas.

Para poder pasar a MPI_Send las columnas tienes que reorganizar el array, en uno en que el primer índice haga referencia a las columnas y el segundo a las filas. Es decir elementos en la misma columna estén en posiciones consecutivas de memoria.

```
int d[10][10];
for ( int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
  for ( int j=0; j<10; ++j)
    d[j][i] = c[i][j];
}
```

Y ahora ya puedes invocar a MPI_Send por columnas.

```
MPI_Send(&d[offset][0], filas*M, MPI_DOUBLE, id_esclavo,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Es una solución, pero requiere hacer la transpuerta de la matriz con lo que se consume tiempo, y eso afectaría al tiempo total de ejecución. Pense que había una manera mas efectiva. Muchas gracias igual..